# Electron JS + TypeScript + ByteNode

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I have a project written in Electron JS + TypeScript.
Interposed the task of its distribution.
I would like to hide the source code
For this I want to use the ByteNode package
I googled a lot, but some superficial information is said everywhere.
What I've done:

1. At the very beginning of main.js I inserted:

   const bytenode = require('bytenode')
2. Moved to the dist folder (this is the folder where TypeScript puts the compiled js files)
   and for each js file ran the command:

   bytenode --compile ./dist/file.js

As a result, for each JS file I got my own * .jsc file

3. Changed entry point from main.js to main.jsc in package.json file

   "main": "./dist/main.jsc",
4. Next, I collect everything with a packer into an exe file with a standard command:

   npx electron-packager . robot --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite

As a result, when I run myproject.exe, I see an error[error on start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4rPZ.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you still need an entrypoint in a file where you need to run `bytenode.runBytecodeFile()` that will run your bytecoded file.